# Create / open directory with creadentials in Windows

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want create directory with Active directory user credentials, only that user has access for directory manipulation like opening listing files, reading files etc.

```
 public void CreateDirectory(int value)
    {
        string drive = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath);
        string path = "D://" + "4524l";
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        string domainAndUsername = "456456.com" + @"\" + "guserone";
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://124.com", domainAndUsername, "a55in123*");


        //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        object obj = entry.NativeObject;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + "guserone" + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();   

        DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = dinfo.GetAccessControl();
        //myDirectorySecurity.SetOwner(newUser);
        myDirectorySecurity = RemoveExplicitSecurity(myDirectorySecurity);
        dinfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
        myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(domainAndUsername,
                                         FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dinfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
        myDirectorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
    }

    private static DirectorySecurity RemoveExplicitSecurity(DirectorySecurity directorySecurity)
    {
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = directorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
            directorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(rule);
        return directorySecurity;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are dealing with a simple scenario, you are probably looking for Directory.CreateDirectory(string path, DirectorySecurity directorySecurity), which you can find documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb.aspx).

There's a decent example there that includes creation of basic access controls.

Comment: I am doing like this, But here all others have access to open directory. I want only that user should have access.

Comment: +1. @Mahantesh - reading something on ACL in Windows may be good idea... Most likely you are looking for stop inheritance, removing all permissions and adding just one you want. Something like [FileSystemAccessRule constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw.aspx) and `DirectorySecurity.SetAccessRule` linked in the answer should get you started.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Please see updated question, With that also every one will access.

Comment: @Mahantesh I don't see removal of inheritance in your sample... Consider first using `cacls` command line too or normal UI to configure access the way you want and than mimic it with code. Good luck. Just make sure not to set "deny - everyone" on your drive during experiments :)

Comment: myDirectorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);this is code to remove inheritance